# How to delete rows with duplicate values in succeeding rows

Tags: pandas

in my csv data I have a column with a following data:

```
110.00
111.00
111.00 *
112.00
113.00
114.00
114.00 *
115.00
115.00 *
116.00
110.00
111.00
111.00 *
112.00
113.00
114.00
114.00 *
115.00
115.00 *
116.00
```

I read it in data frame and I'd like to delete on of the rows with the duplicating numbers but only if they are immedietely one after another. I marked the rows I's like to remove with an *.
Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using `.shift()`, which can shift a series forward or backward (defaulting to one forward.)  You want to keep rows if they're not the same as the next ones, so something like:

```
 df[df["A"] != df["A"].shift()]
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2]})
>>> df["A"]
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    1
9    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
>>> df["A"].shift()
0   NaN
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     1
Name: A, dtype: float64
>>> df["A"] != df["A"].shift()
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Leading up to:

```
>>> df[df["A"] != df["A"].shift()]
   A
0  1
1  2
2  1
3  2
5  3
8  1
9  2
```